# Python suppress block for KeyError exception and code in block not working (assignment failing)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tearing my hair out on this one and I'm sure its obvious to a pro... I've researched suppress, but nothing obvious I can find about why it won't enable my code.

I have a complex dict (based on imported json). I have a `try:/except KeyError` wrapper BUT within this large processing, I have `suppress(KeyError)` block for specific sections I want to ignore errors (note code below IS highly simplified).

When I reference a key that exists AFTER an exception would have been experienced in a previous line it doesn't populate the variable
(code below)

If I reference the dict key out side of the block it works

I'm sure its something to do with the `obj['a']` causes an issue  to  subsequent lines.

```
from contextlib import suppress

def func(obj):
    val=0
    try:
        with suppress(KeyError):
            dummy=obj['a']
            val=obj['x']     # this doesn't populate, unless I remove line above 
    except KeyError as ke:
        print('error')
        pass
    print (str(val))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    o={'x':99}
    func(o)   #hoping this prints 99
```

Comment: Your dictionary doesn't have an index `'a'`. That would raise the `KeyError`. And from a cursory read from the documentation, `suppress` essentially puts the entire `with` block in a try/except. So, if there is an exception in the `with` block, it skips the entire block.

Comment: thanks @abdur agree it definitely causes a key error, but I thought the whole point of suppress was to allow you to 'ignore' the exceptions without catching each exception per line of code - so is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use try/catch block for every line.